# Не подключается wifi на raspberry pi 3

Tags: linux, сеть, raspberry-pi

Не получается подключиться к беспроводной сети на raspberry pi. Сеть находится, но при попытке подключиться к сети  подключение происходит, но тут же соединение разрывается. Пользуюсь утилитой wicd. Система raspbian. Результаты ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:ba:a4:1a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:328 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:328 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:26668 (26.0 KiB)  TX bytes:26668 (26.0 KiB)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:68:04:60:69:78  
          inet addr:192.168.42.39  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::b3f6:1e61:38e2:eaa7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3632 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3147 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3492653 (3.3 MiB)  TX bytes:498164 (486.4 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:ef:f1:4f  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:105 errors:0 dropped:105 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7003 (6.8 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

`Feb 7 02:17:31 raspberrypi kernel: [ 2171.438884] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb 7 02:17:31 raspberrypi kernel: [ 2171.439000] brcmfmac: power management disabled
Feb 7 02:17:42 raspberrypi kernel: [ 2181.710227] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
Feb 7 02:17:42 raspberrypi kernel: [ 2181.781102] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
Feb 7 02:17:42 raspberrypi kernel: [ 2181.781816] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Feb 7 02:17:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 2182.531561] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb 7 02:17:43 raspberrypi kernel: [ 2182.531627] brcmfmac: power management disabled
Feb 7 02:17:46 raspberrypi kernel: [ 2186.218582] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
Feb 7 02:17:46 raspberrypi kernel: [ 2186.277077] brcmfmac: power management disabled
Feb 7 02:17:46 raspberrypi kernel: [ 2186.484581] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
Feb 7 02:17:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 2186.560969] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
Feb 7 02:17:47 raspberrypi kernel: [ 2186.561417] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready`

Comment: а в логах что пишет  ?

Comment: Проверьте версию фирмвари модуля, а так же файл калибровки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге оказалось, что модуль, встроенный в raspberry pi, сгорел